# mySQL date ranges intersection, how to compare?

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

(I've found the logic of the solution here: [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap))

The table structure is:

```
contracts[start_date, end_date]
```

My form uses two inputs, `inp_start_date` and `inp_end_date`. I want to use their values to select the contracts that are in the range.

Example (pseudo):

1. a contract is valid between its start_date to its end_date.
2. Get all contracts that are valid, between inp_start_date to inp_end_date

What is the best way to set the conditions for this query?

---

***edit***

Examples:
if my `inp_start_date is 5/21/2005`
and the `inp_end_date is 9/21/2005`
then it will select contracts that starts and ends BEFORE AND AFTER inp_start_date and inp_end_date, as long as it was valid at that time range, even partially.

The query will find all contracts that their date range, is intersecting with the inp_start and inp_end dates range.

Contract and inputs example:

```
contract.start_date = 1.1.2001  |#|  contract.end_date = 5.31.2001
input.start_date = 10.21.2000   |#|  input.end_date = 2001.3.21
```

This contract should be caught, since at least a part of it is in the range.

Comment: What is the question actually about? Do you know how to do that in *any way*? It's the basic comparison of 2 columns with `AND`.

Comment: Dates can be compared just like anything else. Use, `<` or `>` or `BETWEEN`. If you have an issue implementing that, let us know with a more specific question and we can help you.

Comment: please re-read my question..
it's not a single date! within a range. it's a range within a range. check the edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're validating your input and that it's in the correct format, you could try the [`BETWEEN` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) or the `>=` and `<=` operators:

```
SELECT id 
FROM contracts
WHERE start_date >= <inp_start_date> AND end_date <= <inp_end_date>
```